# Kotlin delegate all fields by class property

Tags: kotlin, delegation

I have a wrapper class `Manager` that has a property `managerInfo` of type `UserInfo` that I can’t modify. The wrapper class just add business rules around  the info object. In code I need to access properties of the *managerInfo* and write each time `manager.managerInfo.username` is a little verbose.

I know that I can delegate property to this info object like that:

```
class Manager {
...
    val username by UserInfo
...
}
```

And then I can simply do `manager.username`. But the problem is that the info class has about 15 properties and do this manually will be messy.

Is there is way to delegate all properties by means of Kotlin lang or by some library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do [implementation by delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#implementation-by-delegation), which looks like this:

```
interface UserCommon {
    val username: String
    val email: String
}

data class UserInfo(
        override var username: String,
        override var email: String
) : UserCommon

class Transaction(
        userInfo: UserInfo
) : UserCommon by userInfo
```

After that class `Transaction` will have all properties that `UserCommon` does, but implementation is delegated to `userInfo` which is passed to constructor.

The other way is to convert `UserInfo` to `MutableMap` and delegate property invocation to that map:

```
class Transaction(
    userInfoMap: HashMap<String, Any>
) {
    var username: String by userInfoMap
    var email: String by userInfoMap
}
```

Comment: Is it possible do without interface? Because UserInfo don’t implement any interfaces and I can’t modify it.

Comment: @KirillLiubun Unfortunately, no. The other way is to keep properties of `UserInfo` in the map and do delegation by map. See updated answer.